# Why does text inside a non-float container recognize the width of an adjacent float container?

Tags: css

I removed `float:right;` from the class `.floated_right`, the `div` behaves as expected, it ignores the width of the `.floated_left` div and starts at the very left.

Why does the text recognize the width of the `.floated_left` div? I expect it to start at the very left of the container.

```css
.floated_left {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.floated_right {
  width: 600px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  /*float:right;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="floated_left">
  This
  <br />is
  <br />just
  <br />a
  <br />left
  <br />floated
  <br />column
  <br />
</div>
<div class="floated_right">
  Why
  <br />the
  <br />text
  <br />appears
  <br />here
  <br />not
  <br />left blue border?
  <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason being, the floated element takes up the floated space, leaving the rest to the left side. If you want the new `<div>` to take space from the left border, you need to either:

- `clear: left` for the new `<div>`.
- use `display: inline-block;` for the original `<div>`.

[image]

**Case 1: Using `clear: left`**

```css
.floated_left {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.floated_right {
  width: 600px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="floated_left">
  This
  <br />is
  <br />just
  <br />a
  <br />left
  <br />floated
  <br />column
  <br />
</div>
<div class="floated_right">
  Why
  <br />the
  <br />text
  <br />appears
  <br />here
  <br />not
  <br />left blue border?
  <br />
</div>
```

**Case 2: Using `display: inline-block;`**

```css
.floated_left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.floated_right {
  width: 600px;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="floated_left">
  This
  <br />is
  <br />just
  <br />a
  <br />left
  <br />floated
  <br />column
  <br />
</div>
<div class="floated_right">
  Why
  <br />the
  <br />text
  <br />appears
  <br />here
  <br />not
  <br />left blue border?
  <br />
</div>
```

**Preview:**

[image]

Comment: If `the floated element takes up the floated space, leaving the rest to the left side.`, then why the blue-border `div` starts at the very left?

Comment: @J.Joe The floated element takes up the floated space of the content. Borders start from the top. Border isn't technically the content area in a box model and floated elements are for the contents only.

Comment: `Borders start from the top.`? By `top` you mean left?

Comment: @J.Joe Well, top left, the element starts. And since the floats belong to the contents, they take up the space like image. The starting point the of the element, `x, y` is there.

Comment: Why does `inline-block` work? Even when there is a typo `displau: inline-block;` in  your Case 2 code? I think `display: inline-block;` works because the width of the view is too small to contain the second div?

Comment: Actually, remove `display: inline-block;` also works because div is `block` by default.

Comment: @J.Joe Oops didn't notice it... Updated because, the second `<div>` is obviously block, so it gets down. Ultimately my aim was that the `<div>`s shouldn't collide so I used `inline-block` so that having another element would make it float